# MongoDB - Count unique values with group by date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can anyone help, I have a data collection

Sample Data

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "player" : {
        "userId": "unique_1"
    },
    "total": 100,
    "updatedAt": "2020-10-05"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "player" : {
        "userId": "unique_2"
    },
    "total": 200,
    "updatedAt": "2020-10-05"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "player" : {
        "userId": "unique_2"
    },
    "total": 200,
    "updatedAt": "2020-10-06"
  }
]
```

Sample Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2020-10-05", (group by date)
    "uniquePlayers": 2, (count of unique player.userId)
    "total": 300 (sum of total)
  },
  {
    "_id": "2020-10-06", 
    "uniquePlayers": 1,
    "total": 100
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `updatedAt`. With `$addToSet` to add the `player` field (without duplicate) to the `uniquePlayers` array and `$sum` to sum the `total`.
2. `$set` - Set the `uniquePlayers` field. With `$size` get the size of the `uniquePlayers` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$updatedAt",
      uniquePlayers: {
        $addToSet: "$player"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      uniquePlayers: {
        $size: "$uniquePlayers"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rMDrMnNLC1a)